# Find app on computer and send to phone via phone number

Tags: android, iphone

I just recently had my app accepted into the App Store and submitted to Google Play. I have seen it where I find an app while using my desktop and then I can enter my phone number and the app download link is sent to my phone (e.g. http://www.groupon.com/mobile). I was wondering how I could create something similar for my application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement something like [twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms/features) on your website. They provide an API that you can use to send text messages. It looks as though pricing starts at around 1 cent per message. They provide [libraries in a variety of languages](http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) to help you get started.

Comment: More info on Mobile App Distrubution using Twilio: http://www.twilio.com/elements/mobile-app-distribution